# Django model under other app label in admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, monkeypatching

Looking for a way how to assign a ModelAdmin instance to a different then a default application label, even in latest Django 1.8 .

Django project schema:

```
<root>/appone/models.py    # class ModelOne(django.db.models.Model)
<root>/appone/admin.py     # class ModelOneAdmin(
                           #     django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin)
                           # admin.site.register(
                           #     ModelOne, ModelOneAdmin)

<root>/apptwo/models.py    # class ModelTwo(django.db.models.Model)
<root>/apptwo/admin.py     # class ModelTwoAdmin(
                           #     django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin)
                           # admin.site.register(
                           #     ModelTwo, ModelTwoAdmin)
```

With the example above, each of the models appears in *admin interface* within its separate group labeled by application name.

```
  --- appone
        |
        +--- ModelOne

  --- apptwo
        |
        +--- ModelTwo
```

How to tell Django `ModelTwo` place under `appone` label ? (without altering `appone` application sources and its models!)

```
  --- appone
        |
        +--- ModelOne
        |
        +--- ModelTwo

  --- apptwo
        <empty>
```

Comment: Use a `proxy` model: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57125725/1925257

Answer (score 6):

Just add `app_label` to `Meta` class of `ModelTwo`:

```
class ModelTwo():
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'appone'
```

**Warning**: as noted by @guymaro86, this will change the table's DB name and cause migrations.

Comment: This doesn't really work since it has side effects. i.e. it also changes the table's DB name and causes migrations.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered `django-modeladmin-reorder`

Github: https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder
PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-modeladmin-reorder/

Disclaimer: I had very similar issues last year, where I wanted to place most used apps on top of the admin index. Could not find anything that suited my scenario, so I wrote my own :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely take a look on that. Just curious what technique was used before I'd dig into sources. A middleware which intercepts AdminSite views and reorganizes widgets & forms from scratch ? Can't be done in a more simple way, some example to my original question ?

Comment: I'm using a middleware to override the context. It may be possible to just use `app_label` meta to add new models to  `appone`. I haven't tried it. Let me know if that works.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#app-label